# How can I get integer solutions with scipy.optimize.linprog?

Tags: python, scipy

When I solve the problem of Linear Programming, like in the following formula, **I want the result of x all to be int type**

Consider the following problem:

Minimize: `f = -1*x[0] + 4*x[1]`

Subject to:

```
-3*x[0] + 1*x[1] <= 6    
1*x[0] + 2*x[1] <= 4    
x[1] >= -3
```

where: `-inf <= x[0] <= inf`

*next is the python coder*

```
>>> c = [-1, 4]
>>> A = [[-3, 1], [1, 2]]
>>> b = [6, 4]
>>> x0_bounds = (None, None)
>>> x1_bounds = (-3, None)
>>> res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(x0_bounds, x1_bounds),
...               options={"disp": True})
>>> print(res)
Optimization terminated successfully.
Current function value: -11.428571
Iterations: 2
status: 0
success: True
fun: -11.428571428571429
x: array([-1.14285714,  2.57142857])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nit: 2
```

Comment: Linear programming is **not** the same as *integer* linear programming. They are solved by different algorithms, and have different complexities. `numpy` doesn't provide any kind of integer linear programming functionality at the moment.

Comment: There are many heuristics, simplest: round x to ints, then fix feasibility -- if you can. For your tiny example, round `x` to [-1, 2] or [-1, 3]. For rounding with [GLPK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Linear_Programming_Kit), see under  [my gists](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz).

Answer (score 12):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html):

> method : str, optional Type of solver. At this time only ‘simplex’ is
>   supported.

Simplex cannot handle integrality constraints so you cannot solve integer programming problems with scipy.optimize.linprog yet. You can try other libraries like [PuLP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP/1.1), [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/) or [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/).

Comment: This answer is outdated, as the feature is now available in scipy, see the other answers.

Answer (score 8):

Scipy added scipy.optimize.milp in version 1.9.0 just recently.

It also added the [integrality= parameter to the existing linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). So your code can be updated as follows

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np

c = [-1, 4]
A = [[-3, 1.], [1, 2]]
b = [6, 4]
x0_bounds = (None, None)
x1_bounds = (-3.5, None)
res = scipy.optimize.linprog(
    c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(x0_bounds, x1_bounds),
    integrality=[1, 1],
    options={"disp": True})

res.x
```

```
array([10., -3.])
```

Where `integrality=[1, 1]` specifies that both variables *x<sub>0</sub>* and *x<sub>1</sub>* are to be integers.

(I changed a bound from -3 to -3.5 so that it actually has an interesting difference in solution between integers and reals.)

Comment: Nice. I think thats the correct answer to this question. Your code example might be more understandable without using numpy in this very key instruction. Just `integrality=[1, 1]` which corresponds to x0 and x1 being Integer variables.

Comment: Updated with that idea :)  But I think that learning about `np.zeros_like` and `np.ones_like` would be useful for anyone, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by w-k-yeung, and having always wanted to do a little implementation of branch and bound, I cooked up my own version.

Do not use this. It's not well-tested and won't perform well. It won't find all possible solutions. There are too many good, free, OSS solutions to recommend this one. However....

If you just want something simple and easy to setup w/ your existing code, and it's a toy problem, and you don't care about the quality of results (or plan to manually check results for final usage), AND you're just doing this for fun, you may want to have a look at this.

I've implemented the branching as depth-first, so memory usage tends to stay roughly constant (but is a function of the search depth you choose and the size of your model.) I've tried to be good with memory where I could and implemented a few optimizations. It's still painfully slow. I'm playing with a 51-variable problem where each has a range of 0-4 or so, and it'll run for days. Plenty of FOSS packages should solve this in seconds or minutes.

Enjoy! This code is this responder's creation. Anyone is free to use or modify it. It has no warranty. I will not support it.

```py
"""A Mixed-Integer solver based on scipy.optimize.linprog. 

This code implements branch-and-bound on the linear relaxation of a given
mixed-integer program. It requires numpy and scipy.optimize.


Usage examples are given in the test() and test2() functions. Parameters of
MipModel are mostly as documented in scipy.optimize.linprog. The additional
parameter "int_vars" gives a sequence of indexes of the variables that should be
constrained to integer solutions.

Typical usage will follow the pattern of:

    import mip
    mip_model = mip.MipModel(C, minimize, Aub, bub, Aeq, beq, bounds, int_vars)
    mip.set_debug_prints(True)
    best_solution = mip.find_solutions(mip_model, depth_limit=C.shape[0] - 1)
    print(f'  soln: {best_solution.x}\n  objective value: {best_solution.fun}\n'
         f'success: '{best_solution.success}')

"""
import collections
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, replace
import datetime
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import sys
from typing import Generator, List, MutableSequence, Optional, Sequence, Tuple

_DEBUG = True

def set_debug_prints(is_on):
   global _DEBUG
   _DEBUG = is_on

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MipResult:
   model: 'MipModel'
   fun: float = np.inf
   x: np.ndarray = np.array([])
   success: bool = False

   def is_int_soln(self) -> bool:
      """Returns True if the result has integer values for integer variables."""
      return np.all(self.x[self.model.int_vars] ==
                    np.floor(self.x[self.model.int_vars]))

   def vars_to_split(self) -> List[int]:
      """Returns the list of integer var indexes with non-integer solutions."""
      if self.success:
         return list(np.where(self.x[self.model.int_vars] !=
                              np.floor(self.x[self.model.int_vars]))[0])
      else:
         return []

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MipModel:

   c: np.ndarray
   minimize: bool = True
   Aub: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
   bub: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
   Aeq: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
   beq: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
   bounds : Tuple = ()
   int_vars: Sequence[int] = field(default_factory=list)
   method: str = 'revised simplex'
   clip_bound: np.ndarray = field(init=False)

   def __post_init__(self):
      if not self.minimize:
         object.__setattr__(self, 'c', -1 * self.c)
      if not self.bounds:
         object.__setattr__(self, 'clip_bound',
               np.tile(np.array([[0], [np.inf]]), self.c.shape[0]))
      else:
         lower, upper = zip(*self.bounds)
         numeric_upper = [np.inf if u is None else u for u in upper]
         object.__setattr__(self, 'clip_bound',
               np.array((lower, numeric_upper), dtype=np.float64))

   def solve(self) -> MipResult:
      res = linprog(self.c,A_ub=self.Aub, b_ub=self.bub, A_eq=self.Aeq,
                    b_eq=self.beq, bounds=self.bounds, method=self.method)
      if res["success"]:
         result = MipResult(
               self,
               (int(self.minimize) * 2 - 1) * res['fun'],
               res['x'].clip(self.clip_bound[0], self.clip_bound[1]),
               res['success'])
      else:
         result = MipResult(self)
      return result

   def split_on_var(self, var_i: int, value: Optional[float] = None
         ) -> Generator['MipModel', None, None]:
      """Yields two new models with bound `var_i` split at `value` or middle"""
      assert var_i in range(len(self.bounds)), 'Bad variable index for split'
      bound_i = self.bounds[var_i]
      if value is None:
         if bound_i[1] is not None:
            value = self.clip_bound[:, var_i].sum() / 2.0
         else:
            yield self
            return
      # We know where to split, have to treat None carefully.
      elif bound_i[1] is None:
         bound_i = (bound_i[0], np.inf)
      # else bound and value are set numerically.
      assert value >= bound_i[0] and value <= bound_i[1], 'Bad value in split.'
      new_bounds = (*self.bounds[:var_i],
                    (bound_i[0], max(bound_i[0], np.floor(value))),
                    *self.bounds[var_i + 1:])
      yield replace(self, bounds=new_bounds)
      if np.isinf(bound_i[1]):
         new_upper = (np.ceil(value), None)
      else:
         new_upper = (min(np.ceil(value), bound_i[1]), bound_i[1])
      new_bounds = (*self.bounds[:var_i],
                    new_upper,
                    *self.bounds[var_i + 1:])
      yield replace(self, bounds=new_bounds)


def filter_result(result: MipResult, best_soln: MipResult,
                  results: MutableSequence[MipResult]=[]
      ) -> Tuple[MutableSequence[MipResult], MipResult]:
   if result.success:
      if result.is_int_soln() and result.fun <= best_soln.fun:
         if _DEBUG:
            print('\n', f'  {result.x}: {result.fun}')
            sys.stdout.flush()
         best_soln = result
      else:
         results.append(result)
   return results, best_soln


def walk_branches(solutions: Sequence[MipResult], best_soln: MipResult,
         depth_limit: int) -> Tuple[MipResult, int]:
   """Does depth-first search w/ branch & bound on the models in `solutions`.

   This function keeps track of a best solution and branches on variables
   for each solution in `solutions` up to a depth of `depth_limit`. Intermediate
   best solutions are printed with objective function and timestamp.

   Args: 
     solutions: Iterable of MipResult, assumes "not result.is_int_soln()"
     best_soln: MipResult of the best integer solution (by fun) so far.
     depth_limit: Integer depth limit of the search. This function will use up
        to (2**depth_limit + 1) * 8 bytes of memory to store hashes that
        identify previoulsy solved instances. Shallow copies are used
        aggressively, but memory may be an issue as a function of this
        parameter. CPU time _certainly_ is. Remove use of "repeats" for constant
        memory utilization.

   Returns: The best MipResult obtained in the search (by result.fun) and a
         count of stopped branches.
   """
   def chirp(top_count):
      if _DEBUG:
         now = datetime.datetime.now()
         print(f'{len(stack):3} {now.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}')
         sys.stdout.flush()

   num_cut = 0
   repeats = set()
   # Put solutions in a stack paired with variable indexs that need splitting.
   # Pop an element, split it, and push any new branches back on, reducing vars
   # to split by one element. Repeat until stack_limit reached or stack is
   # empty.
   stack = [(s, s.vars_to_split()) for s in solutions]
   stack_limit = len(stack) + depth_limit + 1
   start_depth = len(stack)
   chirp(start_depth)
   while stack and (len(stack) <= stack_limit):
      if len(stack) < start_depth:
         chirp(len(stack))
         start_depth = len(stack)
      cur_depth = len(stack) - start_depth
      soln, split_vars = stack.pop()
      var_i = split_vars.pop()
      if split_vars:
         stack.append((soln, split_vars))
      for model in soln.model.split_on_var(var_i, soln.x[var_i]):
         # Skip any set of bounds we've (probably) already seen.
         bounds_hash = hash(model.bounds)
         if bounds_hash in repeats:
            continue
         # Filter out any infeasible or integer solutions to avoid further
         # processing.
         result = model.solve()
         if result.success:
            if result.is_int_soln() and result.fun <= best_soln.fun:
               if _DEBUG:
                  now = datetime.datetime.now()
                  time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                  print(f'\n  {result.x}: {result.fun} (d={cur_depth}, {time})')
                  sys.stdout.flush()
               best_soln = result
            elif len(stack) < stack_limit:
               new_vars = result.vars_to_split()
               if new_vars:
                  stack.append((result, new_vars))
            else:
               num_cut += 1
         # Save bounds for all but the last layer (which uses too much storage
         # for the compute it saves.)
         if cur_depth  < depth_limit - 1:
            repeats.add(bounds_hash)
   return best_soln, num_cut


def find_solutions(mip_model: MipModel, depth_limit: int = 0) -> MipResult:
   """Searches for mixed integer solutions to mip_model with branch & bound.
   
   This function searches for mixed-integer solutions to the given model by
   branching on the linear relaxtion of the model. Results will be returned
   early (if set_debug_prints(True) is called) by passing over results in
   depth_limit // npasses (currently 3), so depth_limit can be passed in large
   and the program terminated early if adequate results are found.

   The search does not (at the moment) branch on all variables, only those for
   which the linear relaxation gives non-integer solutions. This may limit the
   search space and miss some solutions. To fully exhaust the search space, set
   depth_limit to the number of variables you have.

   If set_debug_prints(True) is called before, the search will also print a
   countdown and timestamps to give a since of how far the search is and over
   what runtime.

   Args:
      mip_model: The MipModel to search.
      depth_limit: The maximum depth of search tree branching. Default 0 means
         branch for each variable in the model (i.e. full search).
   Returns:
      MipResult of the best solution found.
   """
   best_soln = MipResult(mip_model)
   linear_soln = mip_model.solve()
   if not linear_soln.success:
      print('Model is infeasible even for linear relaxation.')
      return best_soln
   if not len(mip_model.int_vars):
      return linear_soln

   # Start with some reasonable areas to search.
   solutions = []
   models = [mip_model] + list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
         mip_model.split_on_var(v) for v in mip_model.int_vars))
   for result in map(MipModel.solve, models):
      solutions, best_soln = filter_result(result, best_soln, solutions)

   # Default depth_limit means branch on all the vars.
   if depth_limit == 0:
      depth_limit = mip_model.c.shape[0]
   # Since we did one split above, we've already fixed one var and done one
   # level, so depth_limit can be reduced.
   best_soln, num_cut = walk_branches(solutions, best_soln, depth_limit - 1)

   if _DEBUG:
      now = datetime.datetime.now()
      print('{}: {} branches un-explored.\n'.format(
            now.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            num_cut))
   return best_soln

def test():
   """Implements the example from scipy.optimizie.linprog doc w/ 1 int var."""
   set_debug_prints(False)
   C = np.array([-1, 4])
   minimize = True
   Aub = np.array([[-3, 1],[1, 2]])
   bub = np.array([6, 4])
   int_vars = [1]  # or [0, 1] or [] or [0]
   mip_model = MipModel(C, minimize, Aub, bub, bounds=((0, None), (-3, None)),
         int_vars=int_vars)
   out = find_solutions(mip_model)
   print(f'test:\n  soln: {out.x}\n  objective value: {out.fun}\n  success: '
         f'{out.success}')

def test2():
   """Implements the reference problem from https://xkcd.com/287/."""
   import math
   set_debug_prints(True)
   print('test2: (takes ~15 seconds)')
   target = 15.05
   C = np.array([2.15, 2.75, 3.35, 3.55, 4.2, 5.8])
   bounds = tuple((0, math.floor(target / c)) for c in C)
   Aeq = C[np.newaxis, :]
   beq = np.array([target])
   # Aub = None
   # bub = None
   minimize = False
   int_vars = np.arange(C.shape[0])
   mip_model = MipModel(C, minimize, None, None, Aeq, beq, bounds=bounds,
                        int_vars=int_vars)
   out = find_solutions(mip_model, depth_limit=C.shape[0] - 1)
   print(f'  soln: {out.x}\n  objective value: {out.fun}\n  success: '
         f'{out.success}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
   np.set_printoptions(precision=3,suppress=True)
   test()
   test2()
```

Answer (score 2):

`scipy` has now added the `milp` function in their upcoming 1.9.0 release (see the official [documentation](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html)) so you can now also solve mixed-integer problems. It uses the performant open source HiGHS solver under the hood.

For your example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog, milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

# linprog
c = [-1, 4]
A_ub = [[-3, 1], [1, 2]]
b_ub = [6, 4]
x0_bounds = (None, None)
x1_bounds = (-3, None)
bounds = (x0_bounds, x1_bounds)
options = {"disp": False}
res_linprog = linprog(
    c,
    A_ub=A_ub,
    b_ub=b_ub,
    bounds=bounds,
    options=options)
print(res_linprog)

# MILP
integrality = [1, 1]
lb = [-np.inf, -3]
ub = [np.inf, np.inf]
variable_bounds = Bounds(lb, ub)
constraints = LinearConstraint(A_ub, -np.inf, b_ub)
res_milp = milp(
    c, 
    integrality=integrality,
    bounds=variable_bounds,
    constraints=constraints,
    options=options)

# milp() returns float values even for integer variables
# so we can cast to int
res_milp.x = [int(x_i) for x_i in res_milp.x]
print(res_milp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a python module that includes a function LPmi(.) to solve mixed integer linear programs. It employs the Branch and Bound algorithm on top of scipy.optimize.linprog(.). It is this responder's creation; anyone is free to use or modify it. It also includes an example in the form of a test(.) function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import copy

class LP:
    minimise = True
    c = None
    A_ub = None
    b_ub = None
    A_eq = None
    b_eq = None
    bounds = None
    method = ""
    fun = 0.
    x = None
    success = False
    
    def __init__(self,c,minimise=True,Aub=None, bub=None, Aeq=None, beq=None,
                 bounds=None,method="revised simplex"):
        self.minimise = minimise
        if self.minimise:
            self.c = c
        else:
            self.c = -1 * c
        self.A_ub = Aub
        self.b_ub = bub
        self.A_eq = Aeq
        self.b_eq = beq
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.method = method
        
    def cal(self): 
        res = linprog(self.c,A_ub=self.A_ub, b_ub=self.b_ub,
                      A_eq=self.A_eq, b_eq=self.b_eq,bounds=self.bounds,
                      method=self.method)                      
        if res["success"] == False:
            return res["message"]
        else:
            self.success = True
        
            if self.minimise:
                self.fun = res["fun"]
            else:
                self.fun = -1 * res["fun"]

            self.x = res["x"]
            
    def get_res(self):
        return (self.x, self.fun, self.success)

class LP_Data:
    
    minimise = True
    c = None
    A_ub = None
    b_ub = None
    A_eq = None
    b_eq = None
    bounds = None
    method = ""
    
    def __init__(self,c,minimise=True,Aub=None, bub=None, Aeq=None, beq=None,
                 bounds=None,method="revised simplex"):
        self.minimise = minimise
        if self.minimise:
            self.c = c
        else:
            self.c = -1 * c
        self.A_ub = Aub
        self.b_ub = bub
        self.A_eq = Aeq
        self.b_eq = beq
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.method = method

    def set_bounds(self,bounds_list):
        self.bounds = bounds_list

class LPd:
    
    data = []
    fun = 0.
    x = []
    success = False
    result = None
    
    def __init__(self,lp_data):
        self.data = lp_data
        self.clip_bound = np.array(list(zip(*self.data.bounds)))

    def cal(self):
        result = None
        res = linprog(self.data.c,A_ub=self.data.A_ub, b_ub=self.data.b_ub,
                      A_eq=self.data.A_eq, b_eq=self.data.b_eq,
                      bounds=self.data.bounds,
                      method=self.data.method)                      
        if res["success"] == False:
            self.result = ([], np.NaN, False, None)
        else:
            self.success = True
            if self.data.minimise:
                self.fun = res["fun"]
            else:
                self.fun = -1 * res["fun"]
            self.x = res["x"].clip(self.clip_bound[0], self.clip_bound[1])
            self.result = (self.x, self.fun, self.success, self.data)
            
    def get_res(self):
        return self.result

def level_iterator(level0, int_index):                                  

    level1 = []
    for k in range(len(level0)):
        for i in int_index:
            if level0[k][0][i-1] != np.floor(level0[k][0][i-1]):
                cur_bounds = level0[k][3].bounds[i-1]
                lp = LPd(copy.deepcopy(level0[k][3]))
                lp.data.bounds[i-1] = (cur_bounds[0],
                       max(cur_bounds[0], floor(level0[k][0][i-1])))
                lp.cal()
                output = lp.get_res()
                level1.append(output)
                lp = LPd(copy.deepcopy(level0[k][3]))
                lp.data.bounds[i-1] = (min(np.ceil(level0[k][0][i-1]),
                      cur_bounds[1]), cur_bounds[1])
                lp.cal()
                output = lp.get_res()
                level1.append(output)
                break
    return level1

def intsol(solution,int_index):
    is_int = True 
    for i in int_index: 
        if solution[0][i-1] != np.floor(solution[0][i-1]):
            is_int = False
            break
    return is_int
 
def feasiblelevl(level, solution, int_index):
    newlevel = []
    solution = solution
    for k in range(len(level)):
        lp = level[k]
        if len(lp[0]) > 0:
            if lp[2] == False:
                pass
            elif intsol(lp,int_index) and lp[1] >= solution[1]:
                solution = lp
            elif lp[1] > solution[1]:
                newlevel.append(lp)
    return (newlevel, solution)

def LPmi(data, int_index):
    level0 = []
    lp  = LPd(data)
    lp.cal()
    level0.append(lp.get_res())
    solution = [None,-np.inf,None,None]
    level0 = (level0, solution)
    level0 = feasiblelevl(level0[0], solution, int_index)
    if len(level0[0]) == 0:
        return level0[1][0:3]
    else:
        for k in range(10):
            level1 = level_iterator(level0[0],int_index)
            level1 = feasiblelevl(level1, solution, int_index)
            if len(level1[0]) == 0:
                break
            level0 = level1
        return level1[1][0:3]
    
def test():
    c = np.array([3.,7])
    minimise = False
    A_ub = np.array([[7.,8],[1,3]])
    b_ub = np.array([56,12])
    data = LP_Data(c,minimise,A_ub,b_ub,bounds=[(0,None),(0,None)])
    int_index = [2] #or [1,2] or [] or [1]#
    out = LPmi(data,int_index)
    print(out)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3,suppress=True)
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I played around with it a bit, and have a few suggestions:
1. You need scipy 1.3 or later to support the 'revised simplex' method.
2. When branching, this code changes the bounds for each branch to the floor or ceil of the last result, respectively. But it also changes the other bound to 0 or None (unbounded.) In cases where there was an upper/lower bound already, this can widen the feasible range and prevent forcing an integer solution. To fix this, I have changed lines  116 and 121 above to keep previous bounds which are not being changed for the search.