# SciPy Linprog() Optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:

Objective function is : min  11+22

Constraints: 1+4∗2>=50 and  1>=0,2>=0

This is a linear example. So we use linprog() function. 
The answer needs to be an integer, how do I set up constraints so the answer is not a decimal?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
c = [1, 2]
A = [[-1,-4]]
b = -50
x_bounds = (0, None)
y_bounds = (0, None)

result = optimize.linprog(c, A_ub = A, b_ub = b, bounds=[x_bounds, y_bounds] )
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make integer programming with scipy.
This problem has already discussed. 
Please check this post :[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101137/how-can-i-get-integer-solutions-with-scipy-optimize-linprog)