# Integer programming using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I try to use a Integer programming solver.

The problems I try to solve are small (typically 4 variables and 10 constraints)

The main issue I face is that I can only use `numpy` or `scipy` and not regular solvers such as ortools, mip, ...

There is a linear optimization in scipy (`from scipy.optimize import linprog`) but it only works with **floats**.

Is there a way to do **integer** programming with scipy/numpy or through a pure python implementation?

Comment: Check out [How can I get integer solutions with scipy.optimize.linprog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101137/how-can-i-get-integer-solutions-with-scipy-optimize-linprog)

Comment: SciPy (or NumPy) has no integer programming solvers.